# Remove current clicked ListBox item (ObservableCollcetion)

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a `ListBox` containing an `ObservableCollection` and a corresponding `Button`.
I want to remove a `ListBoxItem` on corresponding button click.

[image: ListBox]

I have added the following c# code:

```
public ObservableCollection<DailySession> dailySession;
```

...

```
 while (reader.Read())
        {

            dailySession = new ObservableCollection<DailySession>()
            {
                new DailySession { Name =reader.GetString(0) }

            };

            DailySessions.Items.Add(dailySession);
        }
```

In order to remove the `ListBoxItem` I have implemented this code:

```
 private void btnClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       //DailySessions is the Listbox name, btnClear is button name

        DailySessions.Items.Remove(DailySessions.SelectedItem);// returns null
        //DailySessions.Items.RemoveAt(DailySessions.SelectedIndex);// returns -1

    }
```

I have failed to get the index of `ListBoxItem` I have clicked.

Is there any other way to remove selected item from `ListBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cast the `DataContext` of the clicked `Button`:

```
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    DailySessions.Items.Remove(clickedButton.DataContext as DailySession);
}
```

Comment: In order to work _DailySession_ have to be removed from the code. I used this instead _DailySessions.Items.Remove(clickedButton.DataContext)_

Comment: You need the cast if `DailySessions` returns an `ObservableCollection<DailySession>`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
  DailySessions.Items.RemoveAt(DailySessions.Items.IndexOf(DailySessions.SelectedItem));
}
```

Comment: Does not work, _DailySessions.SelectedItem_ returns null .